# ffmpeg changing Codec ID?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am on Windows 7 using a zeranoe FFMPEG build #: 20131213. I am trying to splice an aac file into a video and persist the "Codec ID" of the file I am encoding. When I use MediaInfo to examine the file my input file has a Codec ID of "mp42" however; every time I encode the file using ffmpeg the output always has a codec ID of "isom". I would like use the same Codec ID of "mp42". I figured I could use the 'msmpeg4v2" codec:

```
ffmpeg -i prltest2-series_H264_1100k.mp4 -i AAC-128k-audio.aac -vcodec msmpeg4v2 -bsf aac_adtstoasc -acodec copy somefile.mp4
```

When I issue this command I get an error stating:

```
[mp4 @ 0417e6e0] track 0: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container
Output #0, mp4, to 'somefile.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom
    encoder         : Lavf55.22.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: msmpeg4v2, yuv420p, 768x432 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-12-13 18:51:36
      handler_name    : MP4 Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 123 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> msmpeg4v2)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Error number -1 occurred
```

It works if I remove the -vcodec parameter it works but the 'msmpeg4v2' is listed is an available codec. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please include the full, uncut ffmpeg command line output, not just the parts you think are relevant. Why is the "Codec ID" (as MediaInfo calls it) important to be preserved? AFAIK the `mp42` applies to the overall format (like `isom` which is the ISO Base Media Format) and doesn't have a lot to do with the specific encoder being used. I might be wrong, it could be a Microsoft oddity depending on where your input file came from.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?!